# Firebase authentication issues on my project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have linked Firebase authentication to my project but I still keep getting the error :

The app gradle file must have a dependency on `com.google.firebase:firebase-core for Firebase services to work as intended.`

I have followed all instruction still no luck.
Please have a look at the code and let me know what else i need to add

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
     compileSdkVersion 28
     defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nis.taxiapp1"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
     buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
 optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
     }
 }

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
   core:3.0.2'
    }
      apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My project Gradle code:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter() 
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
 }

 task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
 }`
```

Answer (score 2):

Error seems pretty clear, it requires you to add `firebase-core` library to your app level `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
```

For more information, check official setup guide [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

**Edit**: `16.0.7` is current firebase version on their setup page.

Comment: One other issues my firebase.getinstance(); on the page does not function. If i put that line of code in then the app page  goes all white and crashed the app - closing it down. Sorry this is my first week in using firebase

Comment: Well, that's why we have stackoverflow. But it seems like another issue, which requires another question, stacktrace and your code so it can be solved. I doubt I can help you without these, in comments.

Comment: Thanks anyway for the help